# Foreach loop output

Tags: php, woocommerce

Below is the code which give  output as " SKU:1018 SKU:1026 ".
        I am not able to get the desired output from this code please help

I want output like "SKU:1018,1026 "

```
   <?php
        $new= $order->get_items();
            foreach ( $new as $item ) {
                $product_id = $item['product_id'];
                $prod = new WC_Product($product_id);
                $sku=$prod->get_sku();
                    echo "SKU:".$sku." ";
            }
   ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the desired output of `SKU:1018,1026` with something like:

```
$prefix = "SKU:"
foreach ($new as $item) {
    $product_id = $item['product_id'];
    $prod = new WC_Product($product_id);
    $sku = $prod->get_sku();
    echo $prefix . $sku;
    $prefix = ",";
}
```

This simply sets the initial prefix to `SKU:` then, for each item, outputs that prefix followed by the item number. After the first one is output, it sets the prefix to `,` so that subsequent items will be preceded by that comma.

Comment: But the last item will have a comma after it for no reason, surely that can't be intended

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: the prefix is output _before_ each item, not after it. And, since the initial prefix is `SKU:` rather than the comma, there won't be a superfluous one at the start either. In terms of the example given, the output is `SKU:1018` for the first item, followed by `,1026` for the second one. If there were another, its output would be `,9999`, and so on. Hence no trailing comma.

Answer (score 4):

You want to display all SKUs against the string `SKU:`.

And you are printing the string `SKU` in the loop.

Rather than that, get all SKUs in an array and print it using [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function.

```
<?php
$new= $order->get_items();
$skus = array();
foreach ( $new as $item ) {
  $product_id = $item['product_id'];
  $prod = new WC_Product($product_id);
  $skus[] = $prod->get_sku();
}
echo "SKU:" . implode(',', $skus);
?>
```

It is always safe to use arrays for dealing multiple strings because, you can apply any complex logic with ease.

Again, if there is no data found, array code in the above example will simply print blank without causing any error.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `$sku`

to  `$sku[]`, an array, and the

last line to

```
 echo "SKU:".implode(",",$sku);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
<?php
        $new= $order->get_items();
        $txt = "SKU: ";
            foreach ( $new as $item ) {
                $product_id = $item['product_id'];
                $prod = new WC_Product($product_id);
                $sku=$prod->get_sku();
                  $txt .= $sku.", ";
            }
             $txt = rtrim(", ", $txt);
       echo $txt;
   ?>
```

Comment: You need to `echo $txt`.

Comment: And the last item will have an unnecessary `, ` appended to it.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, that should be taken care of by the `rtrim`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below code,Use implode to get the array value as comma seperated.

```
<?php
    $new= $order->get_items();
        foreach ( $new as $item ) {
            $product_id = $item['product_id'];
            $prod = new WC_Product($product_id);
            $sku[]=$prod->get_sku();
           }
     $skulist=implode(",",$sku);
     echo "SKU:".$skulist." ";
 ?>
```